# Get records where one column has the same values and another column has different values

Tags: sql

I would like to get the record where one column has the same value and the other column has different value. See table below:

| Name | Type |
| --- | --- |
| XX01 | Table |
| XX01 | Chair |
| XX02 | Box |
| XX02 | Box |

My end results will show XX01 since the column Name is the same but the column Type is different. I tried the following sql query which returns nothing:

```
select Name,Type from table where Name != Name
```

Comment: Think about join

Comment: You need both records for XX01?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using `JOIN`, like this:

```sql
SELECT t1.Name
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name AND t1.Type != t2.Type
```

Comment: You should use a simple `INNER JOIN` instead `LEFT JOIN`. Otherwise you will get all rows from table

Answer (score 0):

If you need all the rows for the name which have different type:

```
select name, type from table 
where name in (select name from table 
               group by name
              having count(distinct type)>1)
```

If you only need names with different type then:

```
select name from table 
group by name
having count(distinct type)>1
```