# Update duplicate records where a specific column has different values

Tags: sql

The article below helped me to retrieve duplicate records which have different values in a specific column:

[Get records where one column has the same values and another column has different values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73303683/get-records-where-one-column-has-the-same-values-and-another-column-has-differen/73303854#73303854)

Now I would like to update a column of these duplicates:

```
Name Type  NameType
XX01 Box   XX01Box
XX01 Table XX01Table
```

From the sample table above, I would like to update the column NameType with the column Name and Type for duplicate records where the Name is the same but Type is different. Below is the query I used:

```
UPDATE table
SET NameType = Name + Type 
FROM table where name in (select t.Name,t.Type,t.NameType
from table t
where exists (select 1
              from table t2
              where t2.Name = t.Name and t2.Type <> t.Type));
```

I get the below error when I run the above query:

Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Any idea what is wrong with my query?

Comment: `where name in (<expected set of names>)` <--does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using IN to match a field value in your subquery results, but include 3 fields in the subquery results?

I think you just need:

```
UPDATE table SET NameType = Name + Type 
FROM table where name in
     (select t.Name from table t where exists (select 1 from table t2 
     where
     t2.Name = t.Name and t2.Type <> t.Type));
```

You can't try to match the 'name' field to 3 different fields with the IN statement.

Check: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp for more information.